# docker compose file build docker image with --add-host option

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker file which I usually build with the following command.

`docker build -t foobar --add-host head:127.0.0.1 .`

When I try to write it in docker-compose I am not getting any clue how to `add --add-host` while build, I already searched in docker documentations but no luck.

how to write this in docker-compose yml so that the docker file should build with `--add-host option`?

Comment: this option is equivalent to docker run --add-host, i want docker build --add-host.